# Formatting money values with f:convertNumber

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, xhtml

I had to customise a JSF XHTML template which has 2 different values and their sum displayed

```
<h:outputText value="#{Invoice.totalCharge/100 + Invoice.subscription/100}">
          <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="&#163;" groupingUsed="#{true}" maxFractionDigits="4" type="currency"></f:convertNumber>
        </h:outputText>

<h:outputText value="#{Invoice.tax/100}">
          <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="&#163;" groupingUsed="#{true}" maxFractionDigits="4" type="currency"></f:convertNumber>
        </h:outputText>

<h:outputText value="#{Invoice.grandTotal/100+Invoice.subscription/100}">
          <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="&#163;" groupingUsed="#{true}" maxFractionDigits="4" type="currency"></f:convertNumber>
        </h:outputText>
```

With values displayed as

`720.1252` +

`144.025` =

`864.1502`

I set `maxFractionDigits` to 4 deliberately to confirm my suspicions. It has to be 2 in the end but in that case and thats where the problem is

With fraction digits = 2 you get

`720.13` +

`144.03` =

`864.15`

Which for a person looking at the printout is plain crap. 
When and how should I do the math so that the result makes sense to the bean counters across the office and not techies like us?
I have no access to the source all I can change is this XHTML template.

Comment: Personally  I would suggest to use 3 digit for two input and 2 digit for the sum. Then the user might grasp easily that a rounding has occurred in the addition. In essence when you round all three of them to 2 digit, you can't escape from such a result.

Comment: Can't I floor everything then. With 3 digits it'll be a bit weird but more informative yea